# Curl -F option and ansible URI module

Tags: curl, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible's uri module to mimic curl command, I need to pass options when uploading an XML file.

My curl command has number of options passed via `-F, --form <name=content>` I haven't been able to find an equivalent option on [Ansible's uri docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming non-binary form content here, it looks like you can specify two headers here:

- `"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
- `body_format: raw`

Which would then mean you give it a full raw url-encoded body with all your form parameters contained.

- **Without JSON** (`param=value`)

  The general format is:

  param=***url-encoded-value-for-param***&param2=***url-encoded-value-for-param2*** etc.
- **With JSON**

  With the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`, you could send direct JSON like this:

  `{"param1":"value","param2":"value","param3":6}`

  If sending JSON as a subset of a form, it would be like this:

  `records='{"param1":"value","param2":"value","param3":6}'&action=submit`

  But support for this varies.  The proper way to do this would be to use set `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` send the whole thing:

  `records=%7B%22param1%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22param2%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22param3%22%3A6%7D&action=submit`

From Ansible (formatting modified):

> **body_format (added in 2.0)** ( no | raw | json )
>  The serialization format
>   of the body. When set to json, encodes the body argument, if needed,
>   and automatically sets the Content-Type header accordingly. As of 2.3
>   it is possible to override the `Content-Type` header, when set to json
>   via the headers option.